# .docker folder in home dir is too large

Tags: docker

Using Ubuntu 20.04, I had installed docker, docker-desktop and docker-compose a long time ago. Now, I wanted to clean up some storage in my pc and being identifying the large files, and found that `.docker` folder in my home directory is `68 GB` in stoage.

I quickly ran `docker system prune -a` across both my contexts (all data was outdated and useless to me) and still the size is same. I never downloaded any container of this scope of size.

I can uninstall all related packages and delete the folder manually, but I wanted to know the underlying cause of this and how to fix this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing is I may have myself specified that much pre-occupied space for docker during setting it up.

Go to `Docker Desktop > Settings > Resources` and adjust the storage according to your needs.

[image]